# What characters are legal in a Preference/Property Definition/Profile Attribute name?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

In trying to create preferences via `FuelSDK::ProfileAttribute.new`, I found out that commas are illegal. I get a `PropertyDefinitionNameContainsNonAlphaNumerics` error status message.  The [documentation](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/profile_and_preference_attributes/) I found says this:

> Note: In addition to basic alphanumeric characters, certain special characters can be used in the values that you enter as a subscriber value for an attribute. The special characters represented by the ASCII decimal ( dec) codes 32 through 254 are supported.

But that seems to imply commas (ASCII dec 44) are fine, which isn't true.  What characters are allowed, and what are not?  Does any escaping system exist?

Comment: The hard way, also discovered that "/" is not allowed, and it can't begin with a number.